# ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: Failed to connect to :1433 - Could not connect (sequence) local machine window 10

Tags: node.js, sql-server, model, sequelize.js

> ***** mssql db connected sucessfully ****
> customers
> (node:116) [DEP0118] DeprecationWarning: The provided hostname "" is not a valid hostname, and is supported in the dns module solely for compatibility.
> (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
> ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: Failed to connect to :1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
> at ConnectionManager.connect (H:\codeoptimalsolutions\socialApp\backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js:139:17)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
> at async ConnectionManager._connect (H:\codeoptimalsolutions\socialApp\backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:318:24)
> at async H:\codeoptimalsolutions\socialApp\backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:250:32
> at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (H:\codeoptimalsolutions\socialApp\backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:280:7)
> at async H:\codeoptimalsolutions\socialApp\backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:613:26
> at async MSSqlQueryInterface.select (H:\codeoptimalsolutions\socialApp\backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:953:12)
> at async Function.findAll (H:\codeoptimalsolutions\socialApp\backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1753:21) {
> parent: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to :1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
> at ConnectionError (H:\codeoptimalsolutions\socialApp\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
> at Connection.socketError (H:\codeoptimalsolutions\socialApp\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1641:56)
> at H:\codeoptimalsolutions\socialApp\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1400:21
> at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (H:\codeoptimalsolutions\socialApp\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:129:14)
> at H:\codeoptimalsolutions\socialApp\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:201:80
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
> code: 'ESOCKET'
> },
> original: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to :1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
> at ConnectionError (H:\codeoptimalsolutions\socialApp\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
> at Connection.socketError (H:\codeoptimalsolutions\socialApp\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1641:56)
> at H:\codeoptimalsolutions\socialApp\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1400:21
> at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (H:\codeoptimalsolutions\socialApp\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:129:14)
> at H:\codeoptimalsolutions\socialApp\backend\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:201:80
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
> code: 'ESOCKET'
> }
> }

I tried

1. TCP/IP is enabled
2. checked some answers ntng found all give me advice to enable TCP/IP

   ```
   var sequelize = new Sequelize(DBNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD,{
      dialect: 'mssql',
      host: hostname,
      port: 1433,
      logging: false,
      dialectOptions: {
        requestTimeout: 30000,
        encrypt: true
      }
    })
   ```

When i try to run get query then got this error

```
        Models.Customer.findAll({}, {}, {}).then(data=>{   
                      console.log(data);
          }).catch(err => { //console.log("err",err);
                      console.log(err);
          });
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that Windows Firewall/antivirus/etc will allow incoming connections to tcp/1433 on the target machine?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes i checked in my localy mechane 1433 TCP is enabled and i also add this in window firewall inbound

Comment: @AlwaysLearning when i run direct select query returing results list

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a stab in the dark because I don't feel there's enough information but the error states `DeprecationWarning: The provided hostname "" is not a valid hostname, and is supported in the dns module solely for compatibility.` Followed by a number of connection errors.

Your sequelize config contains:

```
   host: hostname,
```

So it looks to me as though "hostname" is returning an empty string but is necessary for the connection to proceed.

Edit to be a little more useful:

[The sequelize documentation indicates that it defaults to localhost if not set](https://sequelize.org/v3/docs/usage/), but here (I suspect) you are setting host name to an empty string. Try setting hostname explicitly to the database host and see if it connects.

Comment: i checked i am passing in hostname ""localhost"" do u have any configration for this ?

Comment: i Got the solution

Comment: what was the solution?